# Eclipse Line Selection

Tags: eclipse, text-editing

In Eclipse I used to be able to select a line by clicking the line number.  I don't know exactly when it stopped working.  Is this controlled by a Preference?

Comment: Where exactly were you clicking this line?

Answer (score 1):

This is not working in all editors (Java, XML, etc.).